# Solr store expression as variable to avoid recomputing it

Tags: solr

I'd  like to know if there is a way to store a `Solr` function expression in an intermediate variable so it doesn't get recomputed each time.

Take for example my concrete need. I have the necessity to sort by distance (but each distance grouped in a different range set, like it would be the case with distance faceting `frange`). These ranges are user definable and can be of any length.

For example a user defines the range set `1,2,3`, the expression sent to `Solr` would be:

```
max(map(geodist(),0,1,1),max(map(geodist(),1,2,2),map(geodist(),2,3,3))) asc
```

Can that `geodist()` call be stored/memoized, or does `Solr` internally optimize such expressions?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the following but might be worth a try :-

```
{!func}max(map($v3,0,1,1),$v2)&v2={!func}max($v4,$v5)&v4=map($v3,1,2,2)&v5=map($v3,2,3,3)&v3=geodist()
```

The above is called parameter dereferencing.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams

we are assigning the function geodist() to a local parameter v3. This parameter is substituted in another set of parameters :- v4 and v5 which are further substituted in v2 and the main function.

However, the above feature was introduced recently in solr 4.0